# cant run ./gradlew.jar into my windows system linux

Tags: gradle, apache-kafka, gradlew

so i want to install my kafka in my computer based on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62180917/15412999

when i do this into my directory

```
 /mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Kafka/kafka_2.13-2.8.0$ gradle
```

into my directory, it going well

but when i run `/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Kafka/kafka_2.13-2.8.0$ ./gradlew jar`

why it return
`Task'jar' not found in root project 'kafka_2.13-2.8.0'`.

and what should i do so in order to the gradlew jar can be executed? please help SO forum thankyou in advance

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the WSL part of the question? Is it failing only in WSL?

Comment: done sir, i changed my process

Answer (score 0):

Appears you now have the Kafka binary package, which does not require building and does not include Gradle. Notice the linked answer includes `-src`in the path, where you do not

You should follow the Kafka quickstart documentation to start Zookeeper and the broker